# SAS Mapping between two datasets

Tags: sas

I’m trying to map between two datasets using SAS.

`Dataset 1`

```
ID   Start_Date  End Date
Aaa   1/1/2023   5/1/2023
Bbb   10/1/2023  1/2/2023
Ccc   15/1/2023  27/1/2023
```

`Dataset 2`

```
ID      Date
Aaa   4/1/2023
Aaa   10/1/2023
Bbb    1/1/2023
Bbb   15/1/2023
Bbb   31/1/2023
Ccc   10/1/2023
```

I want to filter out all the rows in `dataset2` that fits the time range (between start and end date) from `dataset1` for each `ID`.
For this example, the output should be as following:

```
ID      Date
Aaa   4/1/2023
Bbb   15/1/2023
Bbb   31/1/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple `inner join` will give you the expected result

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select t2.* 
    from dataset1 t1
        inner join dataset2 t2
        on t1.id = t2.id 
            and t2.date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date
;
quit;
```

```
ID    date
Aaa 04/01/23
Bbb 15/01/23
Bbb 31/01/23
```

---

If you have dates stored as a string instead (which seem to be the case following your desired output), consider using the [`input()`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm) function in the join

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select t2.* 
    from have1 t1
        inner join have2 t2
        on t1.id = t2.id 
            and input(t2.date, ddmmyy10.)  
            between input(t1.start_date, ddmmyy10.) 
            and input(t1.end_date, ddmmyy10.)
;
quit;
```

```
ID    date
Aaa 4/1/2023
Bbb 15/1/2023
Bbb 31/1/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data one;
input ID $ (Start_Date End_Date)(:ddmmyy10.);
format Start_Date End_Date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
Aaa  1/1/2023  5/1/2023 
Bbb 10/1/2023  1/2/2023 
Ccc 15/1/2023 27/1/2023 
;

data two;
input ID $ Date :ddmmyy10.;
format Date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
Aaa  4/1/2023 
Aaa 10/1/2023 
Bbb  1/1/2023 
Bbb 15/1/2023 
Bbb 31/1/2023 
Ccc 10/1/2023 
;

data want(keep = ID Date);
   merge one two;
   by ID;
   if Start_Date <= Date <= End_Date;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using double set can solve this problem logically。
The first `set` is to load the dataset 2.And the second one is to load the range (datset 1).A `if` will only output the date that fitting the range.
Try this：

```
data dsout;
    set ds2;
        do i=1 to rec while(^eof);
            set ds1(rename=(ID=ID_)) point=i nobs=rec end=eof; 
            if ID=ID_ and date>=Start_Date and date<=End_Date then do;
                output;
                leave;
            end;
        end;
    drop Start_Date End_Date;
run;
```